# jacob - Can't co-create object

Tags: java, windows, dll, jacob

My environment is Java 7, on Windows 7 - 64 bit. So here's my requirement and procedures I followed

1. I wanted to execute a library called `test.dll` from Java
2. I first downloaded the [latest version of jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/), and put them within a folder, which is included in the Windows environment variable `PATH`.
3. I registered the `test.dll` using `regsvr32.exe` under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (it was successful!)
4. I am running jacob from a webapp, so I made sure that `WEB-INF/lib` has `jacob.jar` in it.
5. I also set a java System property - `-Djava.library.path=c:/dev/jacob/jacob-1.17-x64.dll` (This is where I have kept the `jacob-1.17-x64.dll`)

still I am facing

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
```

I have gone through [many of the SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20can%27t%20co%20create%20object) but none of them have helped me so far

can anyone please guide me to the solution?

Comment: i was getting this error on running `new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application")`. this was gone when I ran the application with a user with admin privileges, strange. Mine was all 32 bit (windows, jdk and office) with jacob-1.14.3

Answer (score 4):

A similar problem for me was solved by changing the jdk from a 64-bit to 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of Jacob Dispatch, line 99 (http://jacob-project.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jacob-project/jacob/src/com/jacob/com/Dispatch.java?revision=1.18&view=markup), the error is not within Jacob (at least not the Java code).
Before digging into the Jacob native code, I would try to create this COM object in another container, say an Excel macro or Windows Scripting Host. I believe you will find the same error, or at least will be able to determine if Jacob is the culprit or not. I suspect not.